# getting status of celery tasks in another server

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, worker

I have two servers running celery.

1 - Web Server
2 - Workers Server

The web server is responsible for sending the tasks to the workers server. The workers performs these tasks.

I would like to monitor the status of these tasks on the web server. Any ideas?

views.py

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def taskCompute(request, uuid):
    """
    Now we have the uuid that identifies the image over we want to apply the process as an input.
    To trigger this view, the url has an uuid, and we receive it to receive the image we are working with
    """

    doc = AnnotationDocument.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
    image_name = doc.name_id
    doc.status = 'Q'
    doc.save()

    image_processing.delay(uuid, image_name)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list_admin'))
```

tasks.py

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
    import os
    from celery import Celery
    import subprocess as sub
    from PIL import Image

    app = Celery('tasks',
                 broker='amqp://xxxxx',
                 backend='rpc://', )

    NFS_PATH = '/home/administrator/nfs'


    @app.task
    def image_processing(uuid, image_name):
        """
        WORKERS job: - Get the images from the NFS pre-processing path
                     - Move them to the worker path
                     - Process the images
                     - Create the PDF
                     - Leave the Results in the NFS post-processing path
        """

        current_working_path = os.path.join(NFS_PATH, uuid)
        local_filename_image = os.path.join(current_working_path, image_name)
        local_filename_annotations = os.path.join(current_working_path, "annotations.json")

        if os.path.isfile(local_filename_annotations):
            local_filename_annotations = local_filename_annotations

        else:

            local_filename_annotations = "None"

        cmd = '/home/administrator/Envs/CESSOR-env/bin/python' \
              + ' /home/administrator/CESSOR/compute.py' \
              + ' --iImage=' + local_filename_image \

        print "Command:", cmd

        p = sub.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
        output, errors = p.communicate()
        print output

        # Get thumbnail of the uploaded image to render it in the detail.html template:
        image_path = os.path.join(current_working_path, 'process_result.jpg')
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        w, h = img.size
        a = 301.0
        b = 200.0
        ptgx = a / w
        ptgy = b / h
        w2 = w * ptgx
        h2 = h * ptgy
        w2 = int(w2)
        h2 = int(h2)
        img_thumbnail = img.resize((w2, h2), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        # Save the thumbnail:
        input_thumbnail_filename = 'process_result_thnl.png'
        img_thumbnail.save(os.path.join(current_working_path, input_thumbnail_filename))
        return uuid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Celery to store task results in the Django database. To do this, use the django-celery-results library. See the Celery docs on [configuring the Django backend](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend).

Once you've done this, you can write a view to query the TaskResult model like any other Django data.

Comment: i'm using postgreSQL database. Does It matter?

Comment: Why should it matter? That library uses your Django config.